# Will there be an official novelisation of The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I know  there have already been books announced that will be go from the end of *Return of the Jedi* up to *The Force Awakens*.

Does anybody know, or has anybody heard for certain, whether there will also be an official adult movie tie in to *The Force Awakens*? All I’ve seen and heard so far are just junior novels, picture books, etc. Does anybody know for certain that we will get an official novelization on this new movie?

Comment: "an official adult movie tie in to Episode VII" just sounds all kinds of wrong.  I know what you're saying, but the choice of words make it sound like something entirely different!

Comment: Isn't that rule 34 of the Internet? (Something like "if it exists, there is porn of it")

Comment: I'd be willing to bet a million pounds that there will be a novelisation

Comment: @Richard - the odds of such a movie surviving without novelization are...

Comment: Difficult to see. Always in motion is the future.

Comment: @darthfuture - Since my answer contains an official confirmation, I thought you might want to reconsider your acceptance.

Comment: Even if there wasn’t an official novelisation, @Richard would write one, then read it, then answer *Force Awakens* questions here using it.

Comment: @pauld.Waite - I haven't seen the film yet. You can all fill your boots until then.

Comment: @Richard: I posted at 4am UK time in a desperate attempt to do that very thing!

Comment: I have the entire tag on ignore and I will be very wary of spoilers

Comment: Disney owns the rights to Star Wars. Can you honestly think of a way they *won't* try to whore out the IP?

Comment: related: [How Many New Official Canon Books are there?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111208/21267)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick use of the search engine reveals many claims that [Alan Dean Foster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Dean_Foster) will write  the tie-in novel ([here's one](http://www.bleedingcool.com/2015/04/18/alan-dean-foster-writes-star-wars-the-force-awakens-novelisation/); there are many others).  Foster's previous experience with the franchise includes *Splinter of the Mind's Eye*, the novelization of *The Empire Strikes Back* and the [uncredited novelization](http://moviepilot.com/posts/2014/05/04/interview-alan-dean-foster-on-writing-the-first-star-wars-novelization-1400397?lt_source=external,manual) to the film currently known as *A New Hope*.

(Updated to reflect the comment after finding a confirmation.)

Answer (score 11):

**Update #2** - In addition to the official Alan Dean Foster novelisation, there's also a young-readers version by Michael Kogge, marketed as "[The Force Awakens - A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization))"

---

**Update #1** You can buy it now from [all good booksellers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WCXL1JW)!

---

<s>Yes there is. It's going to be written by Alan Dean Foster and will enjoy an 18th Dec 2015 release date.</s>

Because it's [published by DelRey Books](https://twitter.com/DelReyStarWars/status/589574989243809792) that means that it'll be an official part of the new Star Wars canon.

[image]