# How Many New Official Canon Books are there?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I want to see if I start reading them, but would like to know how many are they right now. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TL;DR: Just buy Disney stock. They will make money hand over foot.

---

I won't provide a full list of books here because first, it's fluid, and growing. Second, far better places on internet track them, such as:

- [Wookieepedia timeline of Disney canon books](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_books).

  This is - as the name suggested - ordered by in-universe chronological timeline; and marks books as Adult, Junior, and unpublished.
- [Wookieepedia list of future books](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_future_books)

  This should be unified with the future books list in the Timeline above, as they aren't always updated in sync.
- [Disney's official book site](https://books.disney.com/starwars/)

  In all honesty, I didn't actually find a comprehensive book list there, but it's the horse's mouth so should be consulted as a resource.
- [Starwars.com book news](https://www.starwars.com/news/category/books-and-comics)

---

### To answer "How Many?" question:

According to Wookieepedia timline, at this time (2015/12/19) there exists:

- **7 Adult books** (of them, 1 game tie-in, and 5 are set before battle of Endor, so no direct tie-in to TFA)

  This list doesn't yet contain official Alan Dean Foster novelization of *The Force Awakens*, which was released yesterday December 18, 2015 digitally but not in dead tree form till January.
- **17 Young Adult novels**

  3 of them are Junior novelizations of the Original Trilogy. Because Disney can always siphon more money from the kids so adult novelizations aren't enough.
- There also exist too-numerous-to-bother-counting comics and short stories

  - [Wookieepedia timeline of canon comics](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_comics).

  Includes graphics novels.

  - [Wookieepedia timeline of short stories](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_short_stories).

  Mostly includes things printed in magazines like *Star Wars Insider* etc...

Comment: Btw started reading the novelization of TFA, Its Awsome.

Comment: Hmm. I'm debating whether to collapse this into my "canonicity" mega-answer.